# Struts 2 Automatically Open .doc or .docx On Download

Tags: java, download, savefiledialog

Might be a duff question, but I'm tired of googling...

I'm working on a Struts 2 Web App that lets users edit .docx files, which are stored on the server. For example, the user clicks EDIT, then the document is sent to him/her. When finished editing the updated file goes back to the server.

Well, this is the idea. I use Struts 2 `result type="stream"` with `contentDisposition` set to `attachment`. This obviously presents the user with the Save dialog. The `inline` `contentDisposition` is not an option for Word files - browsers won't load it anyway.

QUESTION 1:

Is there a way to "silently" save the file on the client? Sounds like a security threat to me - but I might be wrong.

QUESTION 2:
Next, how do I start the downloaded .docx file on the client? Again, I'm dubious that it's easily done (security and all that), but I might be wrong here too. :D

I know that users can live with the save dialog as long as the downloaded document automatically opens up in Word.
Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is there a way to "silently" save the file on the client? Sounds like a security threat to me - but I might be wrong.*

Not using Struts2/HTML/JS. You'd need to create a signed(!) applet which does that and then embed that applet in the web page.

---

> *Next, how do I start the downloaded .docx file on the client? Again, I'm dubious that it's easily done (security and all that), but I might be wrong here too.*

Also here, use a signed applet. Once you've saved the `File` in the client side by the applet, it's then as easy as

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

as long as the client platform has MS Word installed and associated the `doc(x)` extension with MS Word.

---

As a completely different alternative, you can also convert the MS Word docuement to HTML and then present that in a pure HTML edit form (which can easily be generated by JSP/Struts2) and then on form submit convert it back to a MS Word document. That's also basically what Google docs is doing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's what I suspected. Applets are not my technology of choice. I went back to the users and proposed a simple check-in/out system. They actually liked it, because this allows them to take files home and work on them over weekends (what a sad bunch!). There is only ever one editor for a given doc, so no issues with version control. Thanks for clearing things up.